# update multiple properties using update-method in AWS apigateway

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, cmd, aws-api-gateway

I was trying to update my api method inside resource with the following command.

```
aws apigateway update-method --rest-api-id !apiID! --resource-id !resourceID! --http-method POST --patch-operations op="replace",path="/apiKeyRequired",value="false",path="/authorizationType",value="NONE" --region !api_region!
```

But on executing above command, only authorizationType is being modified leaving apiKeyRequired same as previous.
Is there any way to update multiple properties using single CLI command ?

Comment: anyone who is facing the same problem can consult this aws forum thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=225972

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
aws apigateway update-method --rest-api-id !apiID!  \
--resource-id !resourceID! --http-method POST \
--patch-operations  \   
    "op=replace,path=/apiKeyRequired,value=false" \
    "op=replace,path=/authorizationType,value=NONE" \
--region !api_region!
```